# Can more than 1 mol of gas dissolve in 1 mol of H2O?

Tags: solubility

$\pu{1176 mL}$ of ammonia can dissolve in $\pu{1 mL}$ of water at $\pu{0℃, 1 atm}$, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table). Equivalently, about $\pu{0.94 mol}$ of $\ce{NH3}$ dissolve in $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{H2O}$.
I wonder that is there any gas such that more than $\pu{1 mol}$ of the gas can dissolve in $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{H2O}$.